# Does anybodyknow how to program Muscle Sensors v3?

Tags: sensors, c++, motor, analogread

```cpp
#include <Servo.h> 

const int x =  200 

//Naming the servosServo 
Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo4;
Servo servo5;
Servo servo6;

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  servo2.attach(10);
  servo3.attach(11); 
  servo4.attach(3); 
  servo5.attach(6); 
  servo6.attach(5); 
} 


void loop() 
{ 
  //Printing the EMG data
  Serial.println(analogRead(0)); 

  if (analogRead(5) > 200)
  {
    servo2.write(180);
    servo3.write(148);
    servo4.write(89);
    servo5.write(180);
    servo6.write(180);
  } else if (analogRead(0) < 200)
  {
    servo2.write(38);
    servo3.write(10);
    servo4.write(0);
    servo5.write(16);
    servo6.write(16);
  }

  delay(100);
}
```

- I don't know if the problem is in the code or in the circuit.

Comment: En este web site se habla inglés. ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y traducirla al inglés?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to [this](http://www.advancertechnologies.com/p/muscle-sensor-v3.html)?

Comment: you said nothing about a problem that you are seeing ... remove all of the servo code ... reduce your code to read sensor and print the value to serial monitor